# Why Streamlit does not show me my model prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, submit, streamlit

I'm building a Streamlit app in order to make fraud predictions. The idea is that when the user inputs the requested information, the app shows the if the transaction is a fraud or not.However, every time I try it, it does not show me any predictions, but it returns to the main page instead. Below you can see my code :

`if col2.button('Entrada manual de datos'):
# Dentro del contexto del formulario
with st.form('Entrada manual de datos'):
# Selección del día de la transacción
day = st.slider('Día de la transacción', 1, 31)

```
    # Caja de entrada para números
    hour = st.slider('Hora de la transacción', 1, 24)

    # Caja de entrada para cantidad
    amount = st.number_input('Cantidad de la transacción', min_value=1)

    # Caja de entrada para retirada de fondos
    type_CASH_OUT = st.radio("¿Es una retirada de fondos?", ('Sí', 'No'))

    # Caja de entrada para transferencias
    type_TRANSFER = st.radio("¿Es una transferencia?", ('Sí', 'No'))

    # Caja de entrada para quien inicia la transacción
    nameorig_C = st.radio("¿Quién origina la transacción?", ('Cliente', 'Comercio'))

    # Caja de entrada para beneficiario
    namedest_C = st.radio("¿El beneficiario de la transacción es otro cliente?", ('Sí', 'No'))

    # Caja de entrada para beneficiario
    namedest_M = st.radio("¿El beneficiario de la transacción es un comercio?", ('Sí', 'No'))

    submitted = st.form_submit_button("Submit")

if submitted:
        X_test = pd.DataFrame({
            'day': [day],
            'hour': [hour],
            'amount': [amount],
            'type_CASH_OUT': [type_CASH_OUT],
            'type_TRANSFER': [type_TRANSFER],
            'nameorig_C': [nameorig_C],
            'namedest_C': [namedest_C],
             'namedest_M': [namedest_M]
        })

        # Imprimir los datos de prueba
        st.write("Datos de prueba:")
        st.write(X_test)

        # 2. Realizar transformaciones de los datos
        # Cargamos el PCA y el scaler
        ruta_pca = 'C:/Users/lydia/OneDrive/Escritorio/Proyecto final_fraude/src/modelos/pca.pkl'
        ruta_scaler = 'C:/Users/lydia/OneDrive/Escritorio/Proyecto final_fraude/src/modelos/scaler.pkl'

         # Escalamos
        scaler = pickle.load(open(ruta_scaler, 'rb'))
        scaled_X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

        # PCA
        pca = pickle.load(open(ruta_pca, 'rb'))
        X_test_pca = pd.DataFrame(pca.transform(scaled_X_test), columns=['PC1', 'PC2', 'PC3', 'PC4', 'PC5'])

        # Imprimir los datos transformados
        st.write("Datos transformados (X_test_pca):")
        st.write(X_test_pca)

        # 3. Cargar el modelo y otros objetos relacionados
        my_model = pickle.load(open('C:/Users/lydia/OneDrive/Escritorio/Proyecto final_fraude/src/modelos/my_model.pkl', 'rb'))

        # 4. Realizar predicción utilizando el modelo y los datos transformados
        y_pred = my_model.predict(X_test_pca)

        # Imprimir la predicción
        st.write("Predicción (y_pred):")
        st.write(y_pred)

            # Obtener la etiqueta de predicción
        prediction_label = "Es una transacción fraudulenta" if y_pred[0] == 1 else "Es una transacción segura"

        # Mostrar el resultado de la predicción al usuario
        st.write("Resultado de la predicción:", prediction_label)`
```

I've tried different to comment the whole code after  " if submitted:" to check if it could print like "thank you", but it couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can guess in your code, `submitted` object is defined in a block (as lines are indented), right ?
If that's the case, you need to use [session_state](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state).

Try to replace:

```py
    submitted = st.form_submit_button("Submit")
if submitted:
```

by:

```py
    st.session_state["submitted"] = st.form_submit_button("Submit")
if st.session_state["submitted"]:
```